# Radiator leaking from valve-less end

Tags: repair, leak, safety, radiator, water-circulating-heating

The radiator in my living room is slowly leaking from one of its ends; curiously it's not the end connected to the inlet or outlet pipe, nor the one where the vent valve is, but the fourth one. Pictures here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNmtu.jpg . It is leaking from the bottom-left end, where you can see the red container and and some corrosion in the pictures of the detail (with and without that plastic cap that seems to be there only for looks).

I suppose that the only long-term solution is replacing it, especially because of the corrosion. However, is there a temporary fix that can let me carry on for a few months/years without immediate danger? For the moment the leak is only a very slow drip; I put a container and after days there are only a few drops that do not even cover the bottom. I could even think about leaving it this way, if there is no risk of it suddenly flooding my floor without warnings.

The house is fairly recent (2008).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a bad spot to be leaking considering that it's only about 12 years old. It's leaking where an attachment fitting is welded to the tank and with the amount of corrosion around it, a temporary fix isn't a good idea. It's rusted all the way around and it could start leaking a lot more without any warning since there is pressure in those pipes. You really need to think about getting that replaced.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "it's a bad spot to be leaking", do you mean to suggest that this is not normal and there might have been a manufacturing or installation issue?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  I'd have to go with a manufacturing defect  over installation because nothing's installed there. The powder coat and rust proofing just didn't work.

Comment: Thanks; in the end I decided to call a plumber rather than trying to fix it myself.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni  Update us with the results  and a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Close the flow and return valves.

Unscrew the metal blanking plug, block the radiator outlet with your hand to prevent further loss of water, and wrap some PTFE plumbers tape around the plug and refit it.

You may need three hands for this.

Some water will escape, and it will probably indelibly and permanently stain anything it comes into contact with.

You may then need to bleed the radiator from the vent at the top and, if you have a pressurised system, repressurise.